# Replace function MsAccess

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I am trying to use Replace function to remove character from the field.

Example:

```
Country       My goal:
Finland?      Finland 
Poland?       Poland
```

I am writing:
`Replace([Country],"*?","")`  but it's not replacing `?` character.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Replace` function replaces exactly the string given...no need for wildcards.

So `"*?"` is wrong, because that would replace the exact string `*?`, e.g. in `Antarctica*?`.

You need to use `"?"` instead:

```
Replace([Country],"?","")
```

Comment: Thank you! It also was a message: "Ms Access can't update all records 0 records due to type conversion failure....0 records key violation...".                                                     I have 20K records file, 10000 out of it - for "?" removal.      And it did the job.

Comment: Weird. Did it always say "0 records" or did it actually list any records that couldn't be updated? But as long as it did the job and there are no more countries with "?" left, who cares. I suppose this was a one-time action?

Comment: It didn't listed un-updated records. And yes it replaces ? with "". I suppose it was my field formatting problem. I tried replace function couple more times, when needed - works & no more "0 records" issues!  I'll use replace time by time occasionally. Thank you again.