# Replacing String for entire Column

Tags: vba, ms-access, replace

I am new to MS ACCESS & SQL

I am trying to replace all the "[" & "]" within the table.
Am I suppose to use REPLACE command or should Select & Loop through the Table?

Either way, I don't know how to write it in VBA. Thanks for help

I tried this, and it is not working

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT REPLACE" & "(StudentFirstName,'[','')" & "FROM StudentName"
```

See the Table Structure:

[image: figure 1]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace function MsAccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992771/replace-function-msaccess)

Answer (score 1):

Just run an `UPDATE` query with `REPLACE()` function:

```
UPDATE tableName SET fieldName = REPLACE(fieldName, '[', '')
```

and than with the other bracket:

```
UPDATE tableName SET fieldName = REPLACE(fieldName, ']', '')
```

If you want to use in your vba code:

```
Docmd.RunSQL "UPDATE tableName SET fieldName = REPLACE(fieldName, '[', '')"
Docmd.RunSQL "UPDATE tableName SET fieldName = REPLACE(fieldName, ']', '')"
```

Remember: `SELECT` it's used only for ***VIEW*** data and not for edit.
If you want to ***EDIT*** data in your table you need to use `UPDATE`.

Comment: When i tpye in 

DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE StudentName SET StudentFirstName = REPLACE(StudentFirstName, '[', '')"

It pop out a box [Enter Parameter Value]: StudentFirstName

Can i know which part i have done wrong?

Comment: That means `StudentFirstName` is not a valid field. Try copy pasting the field name from the `StudentName` table. Also try enclosing the field name in brackets like `[StudentFirstName]`

Comment: Then please mark as answered.